# SQL Server Data Tools crashing on mild DAX calculation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure, dax

Disclaimer: I wasn't sure where to ask this question, let me know if I'm in the wrong place. Assumed that it's a Visual Studio issue so that's why I'm here.

I'm creating a data model in SSDT 2016 using Visual Studio Community 2015. Whenever I run anything beyond a bare bones basic DAX formula, it crashes.

Using SSDT 2016, Tabular Model 1200. Using Integrated Workspace, not a workspace server. Loaded 2 tables from Azure SQL Database, 1 with about 4,000 rows and another partition of a table 250K rows out of 5.8MM.

DAX expression isn't so complicated (I changed a long name to "Stocks"):

`CALCULATE(
    AVERAGE(Stocks[PX_VOLUME]),
    ALL(Stocks),
    Stocks[Security Name] = EARLIER(Stocks[Security Name]),
    Stocks[TradingDayNumber] >= EARLIER(Stocks[TradingDayNumber -30]),
    Stocks[TradingDayNumber] < EARLIER(Stocks[TradingDayNumber])
    )`

Computer Specs should be more than sufficient:

- 16 GB RAM
- SSD 850 Evo
- Xeon E5- 1620 proccesor 3.6 GHz

**Solutions I've tried:**

- restarting computer (duh)
- changing VS types: I didn't have it installed originally, so it automatically installed the Shell. I uninstalled that, rebooted, and installed VS Community 2015.
- using a different computer
- starting VS from command line with /log. The log file doesn't record the events when it crashes, only before, so don't know how that helps me
- Trying this in PowerBI Desktop and Excel Power Pivot. PowerBI can handle it, Power Pivot also crashes
- Trying this on a workspace server: I used an Azure Analysis Services instance, no dice

And yet, it freezes and I get a "Program Not Responding" error (see screenshot, sorry for poor quality).

[VS Program Not Responding Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwV6e.jpg)

I can't imagine this is a DAX optimization issue, as my expression isn't that complicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check the performance like CPU Cycles and Memory Usage in the task manager.So We can know is it hard issues or software issues,or Due to some other process running background making visual studio to Crash the event

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same problem, always when using EARLIER multiple times in a calculate statement. Since you're using the version 2016, you could try using variables instead of EARLIER, especially since you're refering to Stocks[TradingDayNumber] twice.